# Высота дочернего блока и проблема с отсутпом снизу

Tags: html, css

```css
.overlay {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
}

.test {
    background-color: #f00;
    margin: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="test">...</div>
</div>
```

Имеется два div-а, один родительский, а другой дочерний. Как сделать так, чтобы внутренний блок (class="test", красный прямоугольник) имел наряду с отступами сверху, слева и справа, также такой же отсут снизу? При условии, когда родительский имеет свойство fixed, нижний margin почему-то не работает...

Comment: Фиксед выбивает блок из общего потока разметки и потому нижний margin есть но другие элементы не реагируют на это правило

Comment: костыль: `.test { height: calc(100% - 100px); }`, по-хорошему, это бы всё переделать

Comment: Сделайте padding для родительского блока

Comment: @MonkeyMutant, марджины не на нём стоят - там дело в высоте.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
}

.test {
  background-color: #f00;
  margin: 50px;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="test">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно вместо margin'а дочернего элемента использовать padding родительского:

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.test {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="test">...</div>
</div>
```